# Changing a function to return a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm quite new to C++ and I have written the class and function below:

```
class Person {
    public:
        boost::shared_ptr<Details> GetDetails(const std::string& name) const;
        ...
    private:
        std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Details> > map;
        ...
};

inline
boost::shared_ptr<Details>
Person::GetDetails(const std::string& name) const {
    return map.find(name)->second;
}
```

This works fine, but I have been told to make the function return the pointer instead, and return NULL if the find fails.

I have tried a couple of things, one of which is:

```
class Person {
    public:
        boost::shared_ptr<Details> *GetDetails(const std::string& name) const;
        ...
    private:
        std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Details> > map;
        ...
};

inline
boost::shared_ptr<Details>
*Person::GetDetails(const std::string& name) const {
    if (!map.find(name)->first.empty()) {
        return *map.find(name)->second;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

which gives me the error:

```
error: cannot convert 'Details' to 'boost::shared_ptr<Details>*' in return
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do here.  Any help or resources would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh ... Why?  Who told you to do that?  And why are you following their advice?

Comment: So this *someone* wants you to change your good code into crappy code? *Someone* needs to have some sense knocked into them. You should keep your code the same, just add a check for whether the name exists in the map and return an empty `shared_ptr` if it doesn't. Look at @René Richter's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192506/changing-a-function-to-return-a-pointer/7192701#7192701) below.

Comment: Quite new to C++ and you have guts to write/understand this complicated code! Wow!

Comment: Thanks very much to all that suggested answers, went with returning an empty shared-pointer.

Comment: Thanks Ajay, not new to programming, just C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return the *address* of a shared pointer, so you need to use `&`, not `*`.

Note that dealing with pointers to shared-pointers is a little bit weird.  Why not just return an empty shared-pointer if you can't find the item?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return empty `boost::shared_ptr<Details>`

```
return boost::shared_ptr<Details>();
```

instead of this

```
return NULL;
```

Also returning a pointer to `shared_ptr` is bad idea. You previous version looks better.

Answer (score 1):

You should test what you get by find before accessing `first` or `second`:

```
inline
boost::shared_ptr<Details> 
Person::GetDetails(const std::string& name) const {
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Details> >::iterator i = map.find(name);

    if (i != map.end()) return i->second;
    return boost::shared_ptr<Details>(); // empty shared_ptr if not found
}
```

but don't return naked pointers. It would be dangerous.

Rationale:

- `find()` returns `map.end()` iterator *after* the last entry. So there is no entry to access.
- `map.find(name)->first.empty()` would be undefined behavior, since there may be now empty string at the end of your map.
- `shared_ptr` does all the memory management. Returning raw pointers could ruin all that.